# Redirecting to previous page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a web form which contains a submit button which updates the database.

After clicking the button I need to display a message and go back to the previous page after 2 seconds.

Comment: Share the code that you have been tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless on technologies you use, you can simply store "back link" in the URL as one of the `GET` parameters and then use this URL to redirect user back to the required page. For example, your link might look like this:

```
/action/send/?backlink=/path/to/previous/page/
```

Of course, this link should be URL encoded and will look like this:

```
/action/send/?backlink=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fprevious%2Fpage%2F
```

You can also send this link using `POST` method, alongside with the query for the database you might send. After the link being passed to the backend, you can place this link as a destination for redirect on the page with the message you want to show. You can use redirect by `<meta>` tag in HTML document like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=/path/to/previous/page/" />
```

- `5` — Delay, amount of seconds before refresh will be fired;
- `url=/path/to/previous/page/` — Path for redirection.

As another solution, you can write JavaScript code which will do the same thing. Minimal implementation will look like this:

```html
<script>
  // Wait for page to load
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Set the timer for redirection
    setTimeout(
      function () {
        location.href = '/path/to/previous/page/';
      },
      // Amount of milliseconds before refresh triggered
      5000
    );
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "2;url=page.aspx");
```

this works.